# If I change the node version and do npm install, does the package versions in package-lock.json change?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install, package-lock.json

Suppose, I do `npm install` and then I change the node version and then again do `npm install`, will the installed packages in `package-lock.json` and `node_modules` change? (Assuming the packages were not updated on the npm registry meanwhile)

Comment: Some of the packages can change depending upon their update availability.

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghKainth Assuming the packages were not updated on the npm registry while we the above, will the node version affect the package versions installed?

Answer (score 2):

Was curious about this myself, so I switched node versions, deleted `yarn.lock` and `node_modules` in my project, and then re-installed. **Zero** updates were made to the `yarn.lock` file